# ¿Como usar dos Recaptcha en dos formularios distintos en la misma página?

Tags: javascript, captcha

Tengo una situación bastante particular con un código, este es un formulario básico de registro y login, ambos usan un captcha, pero ambos no pueden funcionar juntos, cuando selecciono login retorna un respuesta en `g-recaptcha-response` pero el registro no, pero cuando elimino el  de login funciona perfectamente

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-login">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a href="#" class="active" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a href="#" id="register-form-link">Register</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <form id="login-form" action="" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="usernamel" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="passwordl" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
                    <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">


                          <!--<div id="RecaptchaField1"></div>-->
                          <div style="margin-bottom: 15px;" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfxAlAUAAAAAFhdx9DyxUqTxAcQoByXhBuGR8t7"></div>

                        <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
                        <div id="alert"><span id="mensaje"></span></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="text-center">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form> <!--Fin de Login-->

                <form id="register-form" action="index.php" method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="usernameR" id="usernameR"  tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="passwordR" id="passwordR" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="confirm-passwordR" id="confirm-passwordR" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 15px;" class="g-recaptcha" id="capt" data-sitekey="6LfxAlAUAAAAAFhdx9DyxUqTxAcQoByXhBuGR8t7"></div>
                        <!--<div id="RecaptchaField2"></div>-->
                        <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now" >
                        <div id="alert2"><!--span id="mensaje2"></span>--></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

El codigo js

```
$('#login-submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var captcha =  $('#g-recaptcha-response').val();
    alert(captcha);
}
$('#register-submit').click(function(e)){
   e.preventDefault();
   var captcha =  $('#g-recaptcha-response').val();
   alert(captcha);
}
```

Comment: en todo caso puedes utilizar el mismo recaptcha para ambos, pues el que se va a loguear no se va a registrar al mismo tiempo no crees?, así que no veo problema en el asunto. Yo tengo un form igual y utilizo un solo recaptcha.

Comment: Como puedo utilizar el mismo recaptcha para ambos?

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia Jorge,yo tuve el mismo problema que usted, el problema es que entran en conflicto las dos input de los recaptcha de cada formulario, por lo tanto debes diferenciarlos. yo les agrege una letra i al formulario de insertar y una letra m al formulario de modificar y funciono perfecto saludos.

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!